# Is it possible to order a query based on a NHibernate multi-column user type, preferably via QueryOver?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have a fluent mapped a database table that uses two columns to represent an IP Address. One column, a string discriminator, `address_family` represents the address family (IPv4 vs IPv6) and a second column `address` a `varbinary(16)` that represents the IP address in Network Byte Order (big-endian with most significant bytes at the start).

Mapping is configured via a custom `IUserType` as follows

```cs
Map(x => x.Address)
    .CustomType<IpAddressBinaryUserType>()
    .Columns.Clear()
    .Columns.Add("address_family", "address")
    .Not.Nullable();
```

The custom `IpAddressBinaryUserType`(implementation shown below) implements `IUserType` as expected mapping the columns to an `IPAddress` as desired. However, there doesn't appear to be any obvious functionality to apply a `OrderBy` clause that would allow me, in this instance for example, to order by the `address_family` column descending, then by the `address` column ascending. I can of course do this manually after the query is run, but obviously this greatly limits my ability to page my data from large data sets.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Engine;
using NHibernate.SqlTypes;
using NHibernate.UserTypes;

namespace NHibernate.UserTypes
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     <para>A User Type for persisting an IP Addresses as 2 columns in the DB (string AddressFamily, binary Address)</para>
    ///     <code>
    ///         Map(x =&gt; x.Address)
    ///         .CustomType&amp;lt;IPAddressBinaryUserType&amp;gt;()
    ///         .Columns.Clear()
    ///         .Columns.Add("address_family", "address")
    ///         .Not.Nullable();
    ///     </code>
    /// </summary>
    public class IpAddressBinaryUserType : IUserType
    {
        private const int AddressFamilyColumn = 0;
        private const int BytesColumn = 1;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Sql Types for custom mapping
        /// </summary>
        public SqlType[] SqlTypes => new[]
                                     {
                                         NHibernateUtil.String.SqlType, // Address Family
                                         NHibernateUtil.Binary.SqlType  // Address
                                     };

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public bool IsMutable => false;

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public Type ReturnedType => typeof(IPAddress);

        #region From Interface IUserType

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public object Assemble(object cached,
                               object owner)
        {
            return this.DeepCopy(cached);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public void NullSafeSet(DbCommand cmd,
                                object value,
                                int index,
                                ISessionImplementor session)
        {
            if (value is IPAddress address)
            {
                NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, address.AddressFamily.ToString(), index, session);
                NHibernateUtil.Binary.NullSafeSet(cmd, address.GetAddressBytes(), index + 1, session);
            }
            else
            {
                NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index, session);
                NHibernateUtil.Binary.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index + 1, session);
            }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public object DeepCopy(object value)
        {
            return value;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public object Disassemble(object value)
        {
            return this.DeepCopy(value);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public new bool Equals(object x,
                               object y)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (x == null
                || y == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return x.Equals(y);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int GetHashCode(object x)
        {
            return x.GetHashCode();
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        /// <exception cref="HibernateException">on inability to do get based on parsing or column mapping</exception>
        public object NullSafeGet(DbDataReader rs,
                                  string[] names,
                                  ISessionImplementor session,
                                  object owner)
        {
            var addressFamilyString = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[AddressFamilyColumn], session) as string;
            var bytes = NHibernateUtil.Binary.NullSafeGet(rs, names[BytesColumn], session) as byte[];

            // no value
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addressFamilyString)
                && bytes == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // get the address family
            if (!Enum.TryParse((addressFamilyString ?? string.Empty).Trim(),
                               true,
                               out AddressFamily addressFamily))
            {
                throw new HibernateException($"Address family of \"{addressFamilyString}\" named by mapping as column \"{names[AddressFamilyColumn]}\" is not recognized");
            }

            if (bytes == null)
            {
                throw new HibernateException($"Bytes named by mapping as column \"{names[BytesColumn]}\" is not recognized");
            }

            var address = new IPAddress(GetBytes(addressFamily, bytes));
            if (address.AddressFamily != addressFamily)
            {
                throw new HibernateException($"Expecting IP Addresses to be of address family {addressFamily}");
            }

            return address;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public object Replace(object original,
                              object target,
                              object owner)
        {
            return original;
        }

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        ///     Get the bytes of an IP Address accounting for length based on address family
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="addressFamily">the desired address family</param>
        /// <param name="input">the possibly truncated bytes that may required 0 bytes affixed</param>
        private static byte[] GetBytes(AddressFamily addressFamily,
                                       IEnumerable<byte> input)
        {
            switch (addressFamily)
            {
                case AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
                    return AffixByteLength(input, 4);
                case AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
                    return AffixByteLength(input, 16);
                default:
                    throw new HibernateException($"Address family \"{addressFamily}\" is unsupported");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Transform an <see cref="Enumerable" /> of <see langword="byte" /> input to a given length, trimming LSB / padding
        ///     with LSB 0x00\"s as necessary
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">the bytes to transform</param>
        /// <param name="desiredLength">the length of the bytes</param>
        /// <returns>the transformed bytes</returns>
        private static byte[] AffixByteLength(IEnumerable<byte> input,
                                              int desiredLength)
        {
            var inputArray = (input ?? Enumerable.Empty<byte>()).ToArray();

            if (inputArray.Length > desiredLength)
            {
                return inputArray.Take(desiredLength)
                                 .ToArray();
            }

            if (inputArray.Length < desiredLength)
            {
                return inputArray.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat((byte) 0x00, desiredLength - inputArray.Length))
                                 .ToArray();
            }

            return inputArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to order a query based on a NHibernate multi-column user type? If so, how can it be done via QueryOver?

Comment: What problem exactly you had ordering the QueryOver? Also show the code of your QueryOver.

Comment: I have no QueryOver to show, the columns are not mapped to the entity. They are used by the Gist  linked UserType in my original post to generate a IPAddress object as an entity property. I'm trying to uncover a way, if possible, to take into account the nature of this relay for the sake of ordering my results.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to expose the address and address_family as property to be able to order them in a Query/QueryOver. Have you considered using `Component Mapping` instead `IUserType`?

Comment: I’m not familiar with Component Mapping, I’ll have to do some research.